# I want to return the dates of fridays (including this one) in excel

Tags: excel, formula

I want an excel formula to return friday dates for last year starting from today. I want to include this friday as well follwing the default format 22/02/2013 in a column. (53 values in total)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you want the data to start in cell A1. 
You could put the following formula in A1:

```
=TODAY()+6-WEEKDAY(TODAY())
```

Then in A2, you oculd put in:

```
=A1-7
```

Then drag that formula in A2 down for the number of rows you need.

Hope this does the trick.

Comment: I needed a quick answer. Sorry for the laziness. Thank you very much.